# SQL Server 2008R2 agent job not deleting old bak file

Tags: sql-server, jobs, agent

Noone on my company's IT is proficient with SQL and servers and an issue has arisen, which no one seems to be able to fix nor is particular eager to.  I know a bit but I'm not in IT hence trying to figure out the issue myself.

Anyway, there is a sql server agent job which is supposed to take a daily backup file of a database and delete the previous backup file.  The part of creating the `.bak` file is working but the deletion of the previous day's file is not.

I've found the code, i think, which refers to this delete bit, or rather the parameters (again I think):

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlmaint N''-D CompanyLive -WriteHistory -VrfyBackup -BkUpDB "J:\Backups" -BkExt "BAK" -BkUpMedia DISK -DelBkUps 1days''', 

   @database_name=N'CompanyLive', 
   @flags=4
```

Shot in the dark, but any glaring errors in this??

Thanks

Comment: If you could try and edit maintenance plans in SSMS, it should have been changed for clean up task or some one have changed to delete records from previous day, if you could expand that in ssms we can go through steps

Comment: If you can post  a screen shot of the  ssms maintenance plan ?